# system() and wait() macros

Tags: c, system, wait

I know that using the call `system()` is like using `fork()`,`execl()` and `wait()`. So the return of `system()` is equal to the return of `wait()`. My question is: how can I use `wait()` macros (i.e., `WIFEXITED()`,`WEXITSTATUS()`, and so on) after using `system()`? Because macros needs the int to which `wait()` points, and `system()` don't give me that int.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`system()` gives you that int.

Here's [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html):

> If command is not a null pointer, system() shall return the termination status of the command language interpreter in the format specified by waitpid().

Here's Linux `man 3 system`:

> the return value is a "wait status" that can be examined using the macros described in waitpid(2).  (i.e., WIFEXITED(), WEXITSTATUS(), and so on).

It also comes with an example demonstrating this:

```
while (something) {
    int ret = system("foo");

    if (WIFSIGNALED(ret) &&
        (WTERMSIG(ret) == SIGINT || WTERMSIG(ret) == SIGQUIT))
            break;
}
```